# What is the purpose of this rail on an intel X540-T2 NIC?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently picked up a pair of [Intel X540-T2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58954/intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x540t2.html)s for various reasons. They're generally meant for (older) servers and workstations but I'm installing them in relatively modern desktop machines.

I noticed that there's a 'rail' at the bottom of the card that I've never seen on any other card I've used. Its not tied into the (rather beefy?) heatsink, or from what I can tell, the ground and runs a significant length of the card. I'm wondering what this rail is for

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

It also dosen't seem to be grounded, though its soldered (not fixed by plastic tabs like the heatsink or jacks)

[image: ![enter image description here]

I mean, I *guess* it could be structural reinforcement, but does the rail provide any purpose, and would I need to connect it to something in a server or workstation application?

Comment: The only possible thought is it's some sort of side rail allowing mounting from a different orientation perhaps in a specific OEM server chassis (Dell).  It not being grounded isn't a problem since it's mounted directly to the PCB and is not near any traces. The card while in a chassis would already be grounded while installed, due to the PCIe ground. I don't actually know the purpose without a shadow of certainty so this can't be an answer.

Comment: This one is off aliexpress, and looks identical to the standard intel version's image but there's a dell specific version that has active cooling, a smaller heatsink and the same rail, and a cisco one that seems identical to this. I did consider it might be part of some non standard mount